# Java generics cast and usage

Tags: java, generics, capture

I have kind of problem with generics inheritance. Below is the dependency tree:

```
public class Attributes {
}

public abstract class Feature<T extends Attributes> {
    
    private T attributes;

    public T getAttributes() {
        return attributes;
    }

    public void setAttributes(T attributes) {
        this.attributes = attributes;
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractFeatureRepository<T extends Feature<? extends Attributes>> {
    public abstract String getType();

    public abstract boolean create(T feature);
}
```

And I have implementations of these feature repositories, like this:

```
public class NodeAttributes extends Attributes {
    
    private String startPoint;

    public String getStartPoint() {
        return startPoint;
    }

    public void setStartPoint(String startPoint) {
        this.startPoint = startPoint;
    }
}

public class Node extends Feature<NodeAttributes> {
}

public class NodeRepository extends AbstractFeatureRepository<Node> {
    public String getType() {
        return "Node";
    }
    public boolean create(Node node) {
        return true;
    }
}

public class LinkAttributes extends Attributes {
    
    private String uri;

    public String getUri() {
        return uri;
    }

    public void setUri(String uri) {
        this.uri = uri;
    }

}

public class Link extends Feature<LinkAttributes> {
}

public class LinkRepository extends AbstractFeatureRepository<Link> {
    public String getType() {
        return "Link";
    }
    public boolean create(Link link) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

I'm injecting these repositories with Spring to Controller via constructor (but in this example I'm manually creating in constructor for the sake of simplicity):

```
public class Controller {
    
    private final Map<String, AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>> featureRepositories;
    
    public Controller() {
        this.featureRepositories = Arrays.asList(new NodeRepository(), new LinkRepository()).stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractFeatureRepository::getType, Function.identity()));
    }
    
    public Node createNode() {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        newNode.getAttributes().setStartPoint("Berlin");
        createFeature("Node", newNode);
        return newNode;
    }

    public Link createLink() {
        Link newLink = new Link();
        newLink.getAttributes().setUri("/home/local");
        createFeature("Link", newLink);
        return newLink;
    }
    
    
    private void createFeature(String type, Feature<? extends Attributes> feature) {
        featureRepositories.get(type).create(feature);
    }

}
```

All is good untill I want to call "create" method in generic "createFeature" where I'm getting compilation error that

> The method create(capture#5-of ? extends Feature) in the type AbstractFeatureRepository<capture#5-of ? extends Feature> is not applicable for the arguments (Feature<capture#6-of ? extends Attributes>)

What I'm doing wrong? Is this because potentially I can pass some other kind of "Feature" than particular "Repository" can work with? How then should I change my map Repositories in Controller so  compiler doesn't complain? I though I should operate exact classes as a key for map but have no idea how to make all of this working. Any suggestions?

Thank you.

**Update 1**. I changed Map to

```
private final Map<Class<?>, AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>> featureRepositories;
```

Changed AbstractFeatureRepository so it now looks this way:

```
public abstract class AbstractFeatureRepository<T extends Feature> {
    
    public abstract Class<T> getClazz();
    
    public abstract boolean create(T feature);
}
```

And changed the methods in controller:

```
    public Link createLink() {
        Link newLink = new Link();
        createFeature(Link.class, newLink);
        return newLink;
    }
    
    
    private <T extends Feature> void createFeature(Class<T> class1, T feature) {
        AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature> abstractFeatureRepository = featureRepositories.get(feature.getClass());
        abstractFeatureRepository.create(abstractFeatureRepository.getClazz().cast(feature));
    }
```

It still doesn't allow me to do that.

Comment: If you know, by construction, that `featureRepositories.get("Node")` can only possibly be a `NodeRepository`, explicitly cast. In fact, that would be a checked cast anyway, so it would fail immediately if it is not.

Comment: My first suggestion would be to get rid of this overengineering. It looks like you just learned about inheritance and generics, and can't wait to put them whereever they're not meant to be. As for the actual problem `get("Node")` is not typesafe, `get(Node.class)` would be, as `Class` is generic. But again, I see this as a huge design problem with generics issues being a minor subplot.

Comment: Can you provide us your AbstractRepository class? Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: @AndriyKucher notwithstanding Kayaman's comment about over-engineering, you might find a "type-safe heterogeneous container" would help. It's described in *Effective Java*; I'm sure you can find it elsewhere on the web.

Comment: My comment wasn't meant in a mean way either. I'm just getting a constant déjà vu with these kind of questions.

Comment: @aBnormaLz That was a typo, NodeRepository extends AbstractFeatureRepository actually

Comment: @AndyTurner No, it is not overdesign. I simplified the code but in my real application I have such 4 repos, each of them working with the objects derived from the same type. I edited a code showing this, so in generic method "createFeature" I have no idea to what exact implementation I should cast to. Actually I considered "type-safe heterogeneous container", now I have an example, will try to implement.

Comment: Well then cast it to NodeRepository and it works

Comment: @All I completed code with 2 implementations showing that I cannot cast inside of generic private method "createFeature"

Comment: Well I found out a solution but i would never use it. This code is just not okay :D

Comment: Why don't you use `Class<T>` as `type` instead of `String`? That would allow you to keep the type parameter `T` in play. I still think it's over-engineered, but of course you don't think it is, because you wrote it. This is probably the third time in a couple of weeks I have seen a quasi-identical question, with the same confusions about generics when the author realizes that the type gets erased and you can't just do what you're trying to do.

Comment: I do SO questions as coding katas. As learning exercises. So I'm ambivalent about the *internet points*. If my answer gets accepted: *Hey, neat!* If it doesn't: *No biggie! It's not why I did it anyway.* But it discourages contributing if [*the questions asked of an OP*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63143140/4465539) are ignored, after generously volunteering time and effort to help the OP. So I'll ask again: ***What problem exactly are you trying to solve with the code example in your question?***. What is ***the intent*** of a satisfactory solution? The ***What?*** Not the ***How?*** Please?

Comment: „*@AndyTurner No, it is not overdesign*“ — My guess for what he's referring to by „*get rid of this overengineering*“ is probably that you've gone through all the trouble of making _`Feature<T extends Attributes>`_ a ***generic class***. But then you're using it everywhere as a ***raw type***. You'd have to concede that declaring a generic class, and then turn around and never use it as a generic class, seems ***unnecessary***. Including ***unnecessary*** things in a design is a very good indication of ***overdesign***.

Comment: I guess answering my ***What?*** question might reveal sensitive company secrets? So I'll take a guess. Your data is a bunch of different _`Features`_; each with different _`Feature`_-specific _`Attributes`_. To persist that data you have some number of _`Repositories`_. Each _`Repository`_ knows what particular type of data it holds by the type of _`Feature`_ it's parameterized with. The _`Controller`_ controls all the different _`Feature`_-aware _`Repositories`_. Its job is to delegate all the different CRUD operations to all the different _`Repositories`_ it's injected with? How close am I?

Answer (score 1):

This code:

```
featureRepositories.get(type)
```

returns an object whose type is the `V` in `Map<K, V>`, as per the docs of `java.util.Map`. In your code, that means that expression is of type `AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature<? extends Attributes>>`.

Let's simplify matters a tad, and assume we have `List<? extends Number>` instead.

This is valid java code:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

that's sort of the point of `? extends`, really. This does not compile:

```
List<Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
```

Now, imagine you called, on your `List<? extends Number>`:

```
List<? extends Number> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
Number n = Double.valueOf(5.0);
list.add(n);
```

uhoh. There is a non-integer in my list of integers. Whoops.

That's why you can't call `add()` here, at all. **You cannot call `add` on a `List<? extends whatever>`, at all**. Any method that takes as argument a `T` where your type is `Foo<? extends T>` cannot be invoked*.

Let's go back to your code now:

You have a `AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature<? extends Attributes>>` - therefore any method that `AbstractFeatureRepository` has that takes a `T` cannot be invoked from this. at all. And `create` is such a method.

The solution is a bit tricky. You can use a type-safe container, if you somehow have a reference to a class representing T (careful; things can be a `T` that cannot be a Class: `List<Integer>` is a T, but only `List.class` exists, you can't write `List<Integer>.class`! - You can use that:

```
public <T extends Attribute> void createFeature(Class<T> typeDesired, Feature<T> feature) {
    featureRepositories.get(type).create(typeDesired.cast(feature));
}
```

is one way.

In general your method signature is problematic: There is just no guarantee that your stringly-typed `String type` implies that the kind of feature desired `Feature<? extends Attribute>` is handled by the repository matching that type.

A second option is to have each `AbstractFeatureRepository` responsible to deal with type mismatches. In that case, you can update the interface to read `create(Object feature) throws TypeMismatchException` instead. Or, have it return a type (`public Class<T> getType()`) and you can go back to the `cast` construct.

*) Well, you can invoke it, if you pass literally `null`, as null is all data types. But that clearly isn't what you intend to do here, thus, not relevant.

Comment: Please read my update 1. Still no luck despite I thought I'm casting to the type repo is supporting.

Comment: Even though this a very nice and detailed answer (you have my upvote) this code gives the same error for me as the original :/

Comment: Yes, as long as ? are involved you're still in some trouble - this is more a general guide on why this is happening, a true fix requires a redesign that goes beyond the code available in the question.

Answer (score 0):

If you've only got 2 things in a Map (or N things, where N is a small number, you mention 4 in a comment), and you use fixed keys to indicate a particular type, using a Map is making it harder than necessary.

Maps are necessarily homogeneously typed, that is, all the keys have a common supertype, and all the values have a common supertype. The issue that you're facing is that you want a key's type to relate to the value's type: this can be done with a *type-safe heterogeneous container* (essentially: a map which you construct such that you can impose the constraints on the relationships between the types). But even this is overly-complex for the problem described.

Use two (N) fields instead:

```
public class Controller {
    private final NodeRepository nodeRepository = new NodeRepository();
    private final LinkRepository linkRepository = new LinkRepository();
```

This is still sort-of a map: the key is the field, the value is the field value.

But the advantage of this is that you've retained the concrete types of the repositories, so you can pass these to the method:

```
private <A extends Attributes> void createFeature(AbstractFeatureRepository<A> repo, Feature<A> feature) {
    repo.create(feature);
}
```

e.g.

```
public Node createNode() {
    Node newNode = new Node();
    newNode.getAttributes().setStartPoint("Berlin");
    // Or, easier, nodeRepository.create(newNode);
    createFeature(nodeRepository, newNode);
    return newNode;
}

public Link createLink() {
    Link newLink = new Link();
    newLink.getAttributes().setUri("/home/local");
    // Or, easier, linkRepository.create(newNode);
    createFeature(linkRepository, newLink);
    return newLink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I don't want to store each of Repo in this controller, this is what I'm trying to get rid of. Currently there are 4 repositories, but later will be more, so I planned to add kind of storage for them so they will be automatically registered with Spring.

Answer (score 0):

To arrive at [*a working solution*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_303709) that is as close to your original code as I could get it, I made three or four relatively minor refactors.

The most significant change though was in *`Controller.createFeature()`*…

```
private <T extends Feature<?>> void createFeature(Class<T> class1, T feature) {
    AbstractFeatureRepository<T> abstractFeatureRepository = (AbstractFeatureRepository<T>)featureRepositories.get(feature.getClass());
    abstractFeatureRepository.create(feature);
}
```

The cast there is the simplest, most type safe solution in my opinion. The reason I'm convinced the cast is type safe is because of the compilation error you'd get if the cast weren't there:

```
Controller.java:31: error: incompatible types: AbstractFeatureRepository<CAP#1> cannot be converted to AbstractFeatureRepository<T>
    AbstractFeatureRepository<T> abstractFeatureRepository = featureRepositories.get(feature.getClass());

where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Feature<?> declared in method <T>createFeature(Class<T>,T)
  where CAP#1 is a fresh type-variable:
    CAP#1 extends Feature<?> from capture of ? extends Feature<?>
1 error
```

If you read the bottom part of the error message carefully, you'll see that the only difference between *`T extends Feature<?>`* and *`CAP#1 extends Feature<?>`* is the names of the two type variables. They both have the same upper bounds (*`extends Feature<?>`*). That tells me it's reasonable to infer that a cast would be type safe.

So, I annotated that method with *`SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`*.

To confirm that the solution is usable, I fleshed out *`Node`* and *`Link`* classes with *`toString()`*. Calling *`Controller.createNode()`* and *`Controller.createLink()`* in [*the solution demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_303709) gets you…

```
Node: [NodeAttributes - Start Point: 'Berlin']

Link: [LinkAttributes - URI: 'urn::foo::bar']
```

I have to admit that what problem you're trying to solve isn't crystal clear to me. So I've made some assumptions based on only my general Java knowledge. Please let me know if the solution meets your requirements?

Comment: You could replace all the `<?>`s in my demo with tighter bounds. e.g. _`<S extends Attributes, T extends Feature<S>> void createFeature(...)`_ , _`AbstractFeatureRepo<T extends Feature<? extends Attributes>>`_ and  _`Map<Class<?>, AbstractFeatureRepo<? extends Feature<? extends Attributes>>> featureRepositories`_. I have a soft spot for _`<?>`_. [*Since they're reifiable*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#:~:text=A%20reifiable%20type%20is%20a,and%20invocations%20of%20unbound%20wildcards.), their type information is fully available at runtime.

Comment: You know, I picked up similar solution. Actually the case, involving cast. That's the only solution I see here and I'm really surprised that it is a pain in such really easy case. I'll post my solution later, but it is similar to what you are proposing.

Comment: Unfortunatelly your explanation why it is safe does not convience me. T extends Feature<?> can be anything actually.

Comment: „*T extends Feature<?> can be anything actually*“ — Can you see the alternative suggestions in my previous comment?

Comment: „*your explanation why it is safe does not convience me*“ — To grok my explanation, [*run this*](https://jdoodle.com/a/2cpE). You'll see „*...error: method <T>m() is already defined...*“ It's ***already defined*** because the type declared by _`<CAP1 extends Foo>`_ and the type declared by _`<T extends Foo>`_ are ***the exact same type***. [*Look here for details*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4). If that example doesn't convince you that  _`T extends Feature<?>`_ and _`CAP#1 extends Feature<?>`_ are also ***the exact same type***, then nothing will.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the approach I used:

```
public class Controller {

    private final Map<Class<?>, AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>> featureRepositories;

    public Controller3(List<AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>> featureRepositories) {
        this.featureRepositories = featureRepositories.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(AbstractFeatureRepository::getClazz, Function.identity()));
    }

    public Node createNode() {
        Node newNode = new Node();
        createFeature(Node.class, newNode);
        return newNode;
    }

    public Link createLink() {
        Link newLink = new Link();
        createFeature(Link.class, newLink);
        return newLink;
    }

    private <T extends Feature> void createFeature(Class<T> clazz, T feature) {
        AbstractFeatureRepository<T> repository = getRepository(clazz);
        repository.create(feature);
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private <T extends Feature, V extends AbstractFeatureRepository<T>> V getRepository(Class<T> clazz) {
        return (V) featureRepositories.get(clazz);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Controller3 controller = new Controller3();
        controller.createLink();
    }
}
```

It doesn't satisfy completely no-cast approach(especially no @SuppressWarnings) but it  is the least evil for me, since cast is done only in one method in controller, all the rest methods work no cast and no @SuppressWarnings.

Comment: The code — *as you've shown it here* —  [*fails to compile*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_303709): _`Line: 27 
type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T`_ and _`Line: 32 type argument T is not within bounds of type-variable T`_. Click the green ***Start*** button at the top of the page of [*that demo*](https://www.browxy.com#USER_303709) to see the compilation failures you get.

Comment: Also, you've declared _`Feature<T extends Attributes>`_ as a generic class. But ***everywhere***, you're using it as a ***raw type***. Here: _`<T extends Feature> void createFeature(...)`_ Here: _`<T extends Feature...> V getRepository(...)`_ Here:  _`Map<Class<?>, AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>>...`_ and in the ctcr: _`Controller3(List<AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>>`_. Everywhere! That's „[*Heap Pollution*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/nonReifiableVarargsType.html#heap_pollution)“. See the fixes for that in my 1st comment under my answer?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```java
private static <T extends AbstractFeatureRepository> void createFeature(Class<T> clazz, Feature<? extends Attributes> feature) {
    ((T) featureRepositories.get(clazz)).create(feature);
}
```

You should modify the featureRepositories accordingly

```java
private static final Map<Class<?>, AbstractFeatureRepository<? extends Feature>> featureRepositories
```

But I don't recommend using generics like this.

Comment: I don't think this is what I need. As I understand you are proposing to pass class of Repository as a param so later I can cast to it. But I don't want to work with implementations, instead of that I want to work with repos on abstract level.

Comment: This is the same approach that you have in your code but instead of passing a sting I pass the class, and cast the repository. I'm not working with implementations `createFeature` function doesn't depend on concrete implementations of `AbstractFeatureRepository`